# Setup a attribute directive via another attribute directive is causing double bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**Background:**
I want to to use ease up the usage of the `<uib-tooltip>` directive in my project to mainly have translated texts and to set further options for tooltips.

For translation, I use Angular Translate. I'm aware I could use the translate filter `{{'TRANSLATIONKEY'|translate}}` directly with `<uib-tooltip>` but I also want to ease up the usage of tooltips in general in my application.

**Description:**
While applying attribute `example-b` via example-a directive due to the $compile the click event on the button will be bound twice (click button). Also, the scope of the directive is not isolated because otherwise changes from the controller wouldn't work anymore.

**Expectation:**
The expectation I have is that I can switch the attribute directives without a double binding to occur.

I also created a Plunkr example to demonstrate my issue, see https://plnkr.co/edit/jMwPzAqLY1XonJQbbIzT.

*Is there any way to achieve this, I'm open to any suggestions?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the priority of the directive higher that the others, and use the `terminal` property of the DDO:

```
 function ExampleA($log, $compile) {
    function linkFuntion($scope, $element, $attributes) {
      $log.info('Directive - ExampleA - executed');

      // To prevent "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.
      $attributes.$set('example-a', null);

      // Sset new attribute "example-b" to trigger directive handling.
      $attributes.$set('example-b', ''); 

      // Compile the element causes double binding but must be done
      // cause otherwise the new attribute "example-b" is not
      // working.
      $compile($element)($scope);
    }

    return {
      priority: 9999,
      terminal: true,
      restrict: 'A',
      link: linkFuntion
    };
  }
```

By using the `terminal` property, the other attribute directives will not be compiled on the first pass. They will be compiled only once in the linking function.

For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - terminal](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-terminal-).

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine. It will call the click method only once.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" example-a click-fn="clickButton()">
```

Example A Directive:

```
/**
   * @ngdoc directive
   * @name app.directive:ExampleA
   *
   * @description
   * This directive set the attribute for the 2nd directive and remove itself from the element.
   */
  function ExampleA($log, $compile) {
    function linkFuntion($scope, $element, $attributes) {
      $log.info('Directive - ExampleA - executed');

      // To prevent "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.
      $attributes.$set('example-a', null);

      // Sset new attribute "example-b" to trigger directive handling.
      $attributes.$set('example-b', ''); 

      // Compile the element causes double binding but must be done
      // cause otherwise the new attribute "example-b" is not
      // working.
      $compile($element)($scope);
      $element.bind("click", function(e){
          $scope.clickFn();
      });
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope : {
        clickFn: "&clickFn"
      },

      link: linkFuntion
    };
  }
```

Comment: This solve one issue but raises tow other issue not use native ng-click and on the other the counter only get update in the HTML because of the interval because the other click handler is out of scope of AngularJS and would require $apply. Thanks mate.